# Pull all the data from Access Database between 2 known IDs Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am new to accessing DBs using VBA. Typing out the query is definitely a challenge. I am trying to get all the data between 2 known IDs. I have 3000 records and I only want to pull (for example) data between ID 256 and 540. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

```
With Recordset
    Source = "SELECT * FROM  RawData WHERE [ID] BETWEEN " & StartofData 'StartofData user input
    .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Building the SQL query? `Source = "SELECT * FROM  RawData WHERE [ID] BETWEEN " & StartofData & " AND " & EndOfData` should work then. • If that wasn't your issue please be more specific: Show the complete relevant code part (see [mcve]). Tell which errors you get and where.

Comment: Yes - I have very limited experience with building the queries. You response answers my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [field] BETWEEN [value1] AND [value2]`.

So the following should work:

```
Source = "SELECT * FROM RawData WHERE [ID] BETWEEN " & StartofData & " AND " & EndOfData
```